# If I hit "Reject Binary" in iTunes Connect to submit an updated binary, will I lose my place in line?

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I've submitted an app for the App Store via iTunes Connect, and the status is "In Review." I don't know if that means they actually started looking at it. I suspect it just means that it's been put into a reviewer's queue.

There's a tweak I'd like to add to it before it goes out. However, I don't want to update it if that means that hitting "Reject Binary" automatically sends it to the back of the overall queue again, and it has to wait another 3-4 weeks.

I realize that it's likely that no one knows how this works, but I figure it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yup, back of the queue. See the bottom question on this Apple Developer Connection [page](http://developer.apple.com/support/iphone/appsubmission/).

Answer (score 2):

We've only had to do it once but it wasnt at all as bad as I had imagined and actually didnt take very long until the new binary got reviewed again. It's much better than releasing a buggy app...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a developer reject action on iTunes will result in the application being 'kicked out' from the current queue and put in the back of the queue. However, if you are lucky you can always try out [expedite review](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/?topic=expedite), that could advance your review.