# Update App Store submission before review

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I uploaded the wrong version of my iOS app to submit to the app store. Is there anyway to revise this, as it hasn't been reviewed yet? I couldn't find how.

Answer (score 1):

Find the `Reject Binary` button in iTunes Connect and click it. That will re-enable the `Ready to Upload Binary` option.

Log in at itunesconnect.apple.com, click on your app, click 'View Details' for the version in question, then you'll see the button in the top right.

Comment: Log in at http://itunesconnect.apple.com, click on your app, click 'View Details' for the version in question, then you'll see the button in the top right. (Comment added to answer above)

Comment: Note, however, that this will move your app to the back of the queue. See also this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543376/if-i-hit-reject-binary-in-itunes-connect-to-submit-an-updated-binary-will-i-l